# Rails simple_form nested checkbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, nested-forms

I have a model which can be modified depending on the role the user has. This setup is made when creating an instance of the model. For that I want a nested form that allows me to select the roles that I want to be able to modify this new object.

So far I got this

```
class Outcome < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :outcome_overriders
accepts_nested_attributes_for :outcome_overriders, allow_destroy: true

class OutcomeOverrider < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :outcome
validates :role, presence: true
enum role: {guest: 0, sales: 1, admin: 2}
```

And as for the form I got

```
simple_form_for(@outcome) do |f|
...
f.simple_fields_for :outcome_overriders do |ff|
    ff.input :role, collection: OutcomeOverrider.roles.keys, as: :check_boxes
```

And the permit is as following:

```
params.require(:outcome).permit(:description,..., outcome_overriders_attributes: [:role])
```

And that's it. I just want to have some checkboxes meaning which role can modify my object. However, so far this hasn't been able to create any overrider.

Comment: Your code and pattern look good; do you have any feedback on what's happening? Do the check boxes show etc?

Comment: Yes, the checkboxes are showing. However I just found something odd. The require is not letting the outcome_overriders_attributes pass

Comment: Can you post the error etc? I can't tell what's happening unless I see it

Comment: Did you that the outcome attributes saves but not the overriders attributes?

Comment: There is no error at all. The Outcome is being created. But no OutcomeOverrider. By printing the outcome_params (params.require..) I don't see any outcome_overriders_attributes, which I guess, is what is causing me troubles.

Comment: Can you post the server log(params) and the controller code?

Comment: To add more on to that, the params are looking something like this.     `"outcome" => {"outcome_overriders_attributes" => {"0" => {"role" => ["guest"]} }}`

Comment: What about the console log for that request? A screenshot? Those params should get it created